# How can you automatically continue a figure on to the next page?

Tags: graphics, floats, page-breaking, subfloats

Below is my code, I have 5 figures (a, b,c,d,e) under Figure 1.. i want them to continue on the next page and not stuck in the middle.

I want them to be one under the other i.e. vertically like the attached picture. Please help.

**EDIT** Hello. I have finally found that the problem lies when I used `float` and `subfloat`.

Can anyone help me how to modify this?
In my main file..

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\usepackage{epsfig,fancyheadings,url,xr,latexsym}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

Comment: a figure is a box so never breaks over a page also normally you should allow them to float, not use `H`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\ContinuedFloat` like this:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering

    \subfloat[Pedestrian level (2 m)]{
       \label{fig:8}
       \includegraphics[width=12cm]{2m.eps}
    }

     \subfloat[10 m above ground level]{
        \label{fig:9}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{10m.eps}
    }


    \subfloat[20 m above ground level]{
       \label{fig:10}
       \includegraphics[width=12cm]{20m.eps}
    }
    \caption{Top view continued... }
    \label{fig:7}
\end{figure}
 \begin{figure}[htb]
 \ContinuedFloat
\centering
    \subfloat[30 m above ground level]{
        \label{fig:11}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{30m.eps}
    }

    \subfloat[40 m above ground level]{
       \label{fig:12}
       \includegraphics[width=12cm]{40m.eps}
    }


\caption{Top view }
    \label{fig:7}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\ContinuedFloat` takes care of numbers by itself.

Comment: hi.. but the caption (a) and (b) does not appear on top of that when i run my full file i obtain errros  Undefined control sequence
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: @Zay Without seeing your code, we are cluless. Does my code above runs as such?

Comment: yes exaclty...i have copied and paste ur code in my work..

Comment: @Zay You have something in your code that gives this error. How do I know without seeing it? Try to compile my code as such (I mean without pasting it in your document). Does it compile?

Comment: yes it does compile but it does not put (a), (b) etcc.. also one of the 5 figures gave only half of the pic...it should have gone on th e next page..

Comment: @Zay It won't go to the next page automatically. You have to do it by yourself as in my code.

Comment: trust me.. i did copy n paste ur code in my thesis... Its my PhD thesis, and in 1 chapter i need to put those pics...:(

Comment: @Zay Eh!. Don't paste it in your thesis. Compile the above code as it is in a new file. Does it compile?

Comment: no when i compile in new file, it gives me as such.. see in above post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17476/discussion-between-zay-and-harish-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I was having some problem with my figures in my text.
My code was tested and working fine.
the Problem was in the package

> subfigure,

it did not work well with Float..

So i did this and it worked well, ie i posted manually 2 pics per page..

```
> \begin{figure}
\centering \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:8}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{2m.eps}
} \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:9}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{10m.eps}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering \subfigure[]{ \label{fig:10}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{2m.eps}
}

\subfigure[]{ \label{fig:11}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{3m.eps}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering \subfigure[]{\label{fig:12}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{4m.eps}
}

\caption{\label{fig:7} my canary
}
\end{figure}
```

Well i am posting this answer as it worked well for me, so if any one is having same issue, you can be sure that the subfigure packages does not work well with Float.

Thanks to all of you who have helped me.